# Dasherize properties for JSONAPI

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, django-rest-framework, json-api

I have this model in my drf backend:

```
class Product:

    price_range = ...
```

I am using EmberData with the JSONApi serializer. I have just found out that JSON API requires dasherized properties. So I need to tell drf:

```
JSON_API_FORMAT_KEYS = 'dasherize'
```

And the property gets serialized in the `JSON` as:

```
price-range
```

Then, `EmberData` does its dance, and I get the `Ember` model property:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    ...
    priceRange: DS.attr('number'),
    ...
});
```

(the old `RESTSerializer` was expecting `priceRange` in the `JSON`, if I recall properly)

So, we go from `price_range` -> `price-range` -> `priceRange` (which is pretty crazy if you ask me). I found all this by trial and error. For drf the corresponding settings are documented [here](http://django-rest-framework-json-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#inflecting-object-and-relation-keys).

Where is this documented for `JSONApi`, `EmberData` and `Ember`? I would like to make sure I have really understood this, and that this is also the case for relationships. The related `drf` config setting would be:

```
JSON_API_FORMAT_RELATION_KEYS = 'dasherize'
```

Comment: JSONapi I don't know, Ember is not concerned. For ember-data, the [serializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer.html) is responsible for those conversions. If it was customized in any way, you should find one in your project, inheriting it and overriding some methods.

Comment: @spectras: thanks! Ember is not concerned in the conversions, but since the Ember models are the end recipients of the JSON object properties, there must a recommended way of defining Ember model properties to make it compatible with what EmberData spits out. Should I call the property in my Ember model `price_range`, `priceRange` or even `"price-range"`. That is allowed by javascript, since those are just object keys. Since Ember / EmberData are rocket-speed moving targets (and the documentation does not keep pace) its impossible to keep track of the current status.

Comment: Ember model is part of ember-data actually. As for conventions… Oren's answer is very good, I'll just +1 it.

Comment: @spectras: actually, you are right, `DS.Model` is from `EmberData`. Which makes me wonder: what happens if you are not using `EmberData`? `Ember` has no models then?!?

Comment: Indeed. There are a few other libs out there that provide other model implementations. You're probably better off sticking to the official one though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [blog post for the `Ember-Data 1.13` release](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html) the Ember data team writes:

> JSONSerializer and RESTSerializer have been refactored and streamlined
>   to return JSON API payloads.

This means that moving forward Ember Data expects dasherized names in line with JSON API. See [the JSON API recommendation for dashes in between words of member names](http://jsonapi.org/recommendations/):

> Member names SHOULD contain only the characters "a-z" (U+0061 to
>   U+007A), "0-9" (U+0030 to U+0039), and the hyphen minus (U+002D
>   HYPHEN-MINUS, "-") as separator between multiple words.

And see some of the example JSON on the JSON API home page:

```
-"attributes": {
    "first-name": "Dan",
    "last-name": "Gebhardt",
    "twitter": "dgeb"
},
```

As far as the models are concerned, [the most recent documentation for Ember 2.2.0](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/models/customizing-serializers/) states:

> In Ember Data the convention is to camelize attribute names on a model

And the example model given with mutli-world attribute names is as expected:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName:  DS.attr('string'),

  isPersonOfTheYear: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

While there definitely has been churn in the recommended naming conventions, I expect that at this point most of these changes are behind us. The core team has taken notice. I believe in the move to standardize around JSON API so that inter-operable and re-usable tooling can be built, but unfortunately that move came along with these changes.

In summary: Use dasherized names in your JSON and camelized names in your models.

Edit:
It seems that while the Ember Data team went with the JSON API recommendation regarding property names in JSON payloads, it is just that - a recommendation. See this discussion on [GitHub regarding the dasherized naming convention](https://github.com/json-api/json-api/issues/323) for JSON API.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I understand the motivation, and see the rationale behind standardizing around a mature and stable spec, so that worlds as different as Django and Ember can coexist (I really hate it when Ember developers overwhelmingly refer to RoR: Ember is supposed to be an independent thing). But still, some decisions in the JSON Api seem  strange: why the dasherized properties? Javascript uses camelized properties all around, and JSON is `JavaScript Object Notation`

Comment: Agreed, but sometimes it's worth it to adhere to strange conventions as long as there are conventions. Thus the JSON API philosophy of being 'anti-bike-shed' - these debates have happened so many time, as long as they are decided, I don't have to worry about the decisions any longer, even if they aren't the decisions I would have thought are the most intuitive. See my edit.

Comment: Yes, I understand that any decision is better than no decision. It is just that this is *another thing* I'll need to remember next time I write a service to interface via JSON Api: "this is called JSON API, but it is actually not very Javascripty". So even though 90% of the clients using JSON Api will be javascript clients, the JSON in JSON API is not javascript compatible. If you are gonna make a decision, why not make the one with less friction?

Comment: True, but I do think the tooling will get to a place where you don't have to even think about that. Eventually the tools will be there to say 'here is a JavaScript object, be it as it may, perform the appropriate transformations to expose the data in a serialized form that is compatible with JSON API' . So, my hope is that you eventually wont need to have to remember to manually perform these transformations at all.

Comment: I agree that going with a more widespread format typical of JavaScript in the wild would have been a more intuitive choice though. But, the time to debate that was before the JSON API 1.0 spec was published.